# Drush cannot connect to mysql

Tags: drush

I have a problem with Drush to enable or disable module. But downloading modules works perfect! However I want to use Drush in its full range.

Yesterday, I saw my Drush would not succeed in connecting to the database. I already tried to update the path in .bash_profile to the AMPPS path. But after that, my bash cannot find the database any more. I already deleted the line but bash don't find mysql.

Anybody has an idea about what to do to resolve this?

**Below are the various messages I received:**

> Sams-MacBook-Pro:demo Sam$ drush en views -d
>
> Starting Drush preflight. [0.01 sec, 1.82 MB]                        [preflight]
>
> Cache HIT cid:                                                         [debug]
>
> 7.0-dev-commandfiles-0-9942ce60ec4ba1e3ca6f94d08d021773 [0.01 sec,
>   1.88 MB] Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.09 sec, 5.75 MB]                   [bootstrap]
>
> Bootstrap to phase 6. [0.09 sec, 5.76 MB]                            [bootstrap]
>
> Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.09 sec,    [bootstrap]
>   5.76 MB]
>
> Initialized Drupal 7.34 root directory at                              [notice]
>
> /Applications/AMPPS/www/demo [0.1 sec, 6.09 MB]
>
> Cache HIT cid:                                                         [debug]
>   7.0-dev-commandfiles-1-68c4337f6c538cdf6d3ca715c4afb7a3 [0.1 sec,
>   4.17 MB]
>
> Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.1 sec, 4.18[bootstrap] MB]
>
> Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.1 sec, 4.18 MB]    [notice]
>
> Cache HIT cid:                                                         [debug]
>   7.0-dev-commandfiles-2-9518eda12b48158193bd617384d95a7d [0.11 sec,
>   4.18 MB]
>
> Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.11[bootstrap] sec, 4.18 MB]
>
> sql-query: SELECT 1; [0.11 sec, 4.3 MB]                              [status]
>
> Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/private/tmp/drush_9NOj8N
>   --database=demoDB --host=127.0.0.1 --silent  < /private/tmp/drush_gIJn4w
>
> sh: mysql: command not found
>
> Bootstrap to phase 5. [0.12 sec, 4.3 MB]                             [bootstrap]
>
> Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will   [error]
>
> need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run
>   this command. [0.12 sec, 4.3 MB]
>
> The drush command 'en views' could not be executed. [0.12 sec, 4.3   [error] MB]
>
> Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.         [error]
>
> Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
>
> - bootstrap a site that
>     has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this
>     case you can select another site with a working database setup by
>     specifying the URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command
>     line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for details.
> - connect the
>     database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli
>     may have no access to it in a jailed shell. See
>     http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.

**Drush was attempting to connect to:**

> Drupal version         :  7.34
>   Site URI               :  http://default
>   Database driver        :  mysql
>   Database hostname      :  127.0.0.1
>   Database port          :
>   Database username      :  demoDB
>   Database name          :  demoDB
>   PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php
>   PHP configuration      :
>   PHP OS                 :  Darwin
>   Drush version          :  7.0-dev
>   Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
>   Drush configuration    :
>   Drush alias files      :
>   Drupal root            :  /Applications/AMPPS/www/demo
>   Site path              :  sites/default
>
> [0.17 sec, 6.42 MB]   Sams-MacBook-Pro:demo Sam$

Answer (score -2):

Ok i solved that problem my own. I have deleted the Drush Version 7.x and installed the 6.x Version. it works like a charm.